# Pyspark - "Recursive" function involving last day

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, pyspark

I'm working on a process in pyspark which I have a dataframe and I'm trying to add one more column (using withColumn method).

The problem is that the formula is:

> STATUS1 = If 'PETP-today' > 0 then 'Status1 last day' + 'PETP-today' else 0

Each result for Status1 involves status1 from the last day result.

One solution I found was to create a pandas dataframe and run the records one by one till I can calculate each, using variables. However I'll have performance issues. Can you help?

Consider the dataframe columns: Date (daily) / PETP (Float)/ STATUS1? (Float)

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to your solution is the [lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lag-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-int-) function. Try this (for simplicity, I am assuming integer data for all columns):

First, shift the column by one day up

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

columns = ['date', 'petp', 'status']
data = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3,3,3), (4,4,4), (5,5,5)]
pd_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=columns)
spark_data = spark.createDataFrame(pd_data)

spark_data_with_lag = spark_data.withColumn("status_last_day", F.lag("status", 1, 0).over(Window.orderBy("date")))
spark_data_with_lag.show()

+----+----+------+---------------+
|date|petp|status|status_last_day|
+----+----+------+---------------+
|   1|   1|     1|              0|
|   2|   2|     2|              1|
|   3|   3|     3|              2|
|   4|   4|     4|              3|
|   5|   5|     5|              4|
+----+----+------+---------------+
```

Then use that data in your conditional

```
status2 = spark_data_with_lag.withColumn("status2", F.when(F.col("date") > 0, F.col("petp") + F.col("status_last_day")).otherwise(0))
status2.show()

+----+----+------+---------------+-------+
|date|petp|status|status_last_day|status2|
+----+----+------+---------------+-------+
|   1|   1|     1|              0|      1|
|   2|   2|     2|              1|      3|
|   3|   3|     3|              2|      5|
|   4|   4|     4|              3|      7|
|   5|   5|     5|              4|      9|
+----+----+------+---------------+-------+
```

I hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hello Martin, thanks for your answer. The problem is that the status column you created depends on the status_last_day by itself. This number doesn't exist without referencing the last one. Is it clear?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean. Please update your question with an input dataframe and expected output.